# How to perform: Upload Image > Recognize Text > Make Image Searchable > Store into DB?

Tags: java, php, python, ocr

I need to know how to perform the procedure, you already have read in the title.

You'll upload an image (e.g. a piece of text, an article) and on server-side the text will be recognized via OCR and stored into a database.

Which would be the best programming language for it? It should be a browser application.
I found the ocropus project, but how can I combine it to common web scripting languages like PHP? Is it possible at all? Didn't have worked with Python yet.

Or a totally different approach..? Java Enterprise?

Let's rock that,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use this php library i use for recognize text from images and store the text readed into database

http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2874/download/targz.html

download the rar package and run example.php and then example1.php to see how it works

here you have an image upload example:
http://www.reconn.us/content/view/30/51/

hope this helps